# Hiding the Perspective toolbar in Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

In Luna ,getPerspectiveBar() has been removed from WorkbenchWindow.Is there any other way to get the same functionality.My aim is ,I want to access the setvisible() method.

Answer (score 0):

The `IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer` has a `setShowPerspectiveBar` method. I think that is the only official way to change the perspective bar visibility.

Note that `WorkbenchWindow` is an internal class, using it violates the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: i can't initialize the IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer. if i use PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow() method.i am getting class casting error

Comment: I didn't say you could cast it. IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer is only available during the RCP startup. There is no official way to change the perspective bar visibility once the RCP is running.

Comment: SO,once the RCP is launched ,we could't hide the perspective bar.Is it so?

Comment: You might be able to do something by manipulating the e4 application model using 'EModelService', but that would require a lot of research.

Comment: okay.During startup of RCP ,What is proper way to initialize the  IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer.

Comment: It is available in the RCP's `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`

Comment: In Luna,By Right click on the Perspective bar,we are able to hide and restore the Perspective bar.for this they have code  in org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt package .Method is createToolControlMenu() of ToolControlRenderer class.

Comment: Is there any other way to use this code to hide the Perspective bar.